# Drupal 7.52: Text editor not appearing anymore

Tags: drupal

Adding in new content on Drupal 7.52:

After the latest browser updates of Firefox and Chrome the text editor TiNYMCE does not appear anymore. All I see are the text areas. Switching between 'Full HTML' and  'Filtered HTML' does not make a difference.

Everything was working fine on Firefox 49.
Now on version 50 I see this error in the console:

```
The resource from "[SERVER ADDRESS]/misc/jquery.once.js?v=1.2” 
was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

Can anyone help here? I tried to install a different editor, but that did not change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser is expecting the MIME type of the file to be set. I'd check the source to make sure the appropriate MIME type is being set for the file. here's a list of MIME types for you: https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/mime-types-complete-list/ -- head down to the .js section and compare it against your source, first checking jquery.once.js.

Also, check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options

Comment: Hi Steven, thanks for your reply!
The problem is that I did not do anything to the source at all. A long time ago I installed a Drupal7 + TinyMCE and it worked.

It stopped working when the browsers got updated...

Comment: Yeah the thing is that in 49  Firefox may not have checked for a MIME type mismatch then in 50 it did. So, even if you didn't touch the source it is now and issue because FF is now checking.